# Correct URI on NewWindow event from Web Browser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms, webbrowser-control

I am using .net webbrowser control and want to capture NewWindow event. When ever webpage inside webbrowser tries to open new window. 
With my own implementation of NewWindow3 method, I am recieving event but in some case URI is not correct. Its stripping the url after "#".

```
[PreserveSig, MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType =       MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x111)]
void NewWindow3([In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] ref object ppDisp, [In, Out] ref bool Cancel, [In] uint dwFlags, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string bstrUrlContext, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string bstrUrl);
```

I read this in one of the blog and looks this is limitation of NewWindows3
"They are implemented as MSHTML host windows, which allows them to render and display HTML content but not hyperlinks between documents."

Is there any other way to capture event and complete URI, including hyperlinks within documents?